# INDEX-MATCH SPILL ERROr

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

When I use the formulas :

**=IFERROR(INDEX('List of products'!A$2:A$430,SMALL(IF('List of products'!H$2:H$430<>"",ROW('List of products'!A$2:A$430)-ROW('List of products'!A$2)+1),ROWS('List of products'!A$2:A2))),"")**

**=IFERROR(INDEX('List of products'!H$2:H$430,SMALL(IF('List of products'!H$2:H$430<>"",ROW('List of products'!A$2:A$430)-ROW('List of products'!A$2)+1),ROWS('List of products'!A$2:A2))),"")**

it works just fine for a range until 430. **How can I make so it works for the entire column A and H and not just until 430?** I tried the conventional way of using A:A and H:H but it returns an SPILL error

Comment: Could you provide a sample about your source table here?

Comment: Can you provide the versions of the formula which produce the `#SPILL!` error. I have been unable to reproduce your error. If I understand your formulas correctly, you are trying to produce versions of columns `A` and `H` (on worksheet "List of Products") which remove any row where the cell in column `H` is empty. Is that correct?